# How to remove a section from an audio and keep the rest with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to remove a section from an audio. For example I want to remove from 30s to 45s and have the rest with me. What I'm doing is the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]atrim=duration=30[a];[0]atrim=start=45[b];[a][b]concat" output.mp3
```

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

What I obtain is the following error:

```
[Parsed_atrim_0 @ 00000000000c8700] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_atrim_0' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_concat_2' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002435260] Cannot create the link atrim:0 -> concat:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 7):

The [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) by default expects to output 1 video stream and 0 audio streams. Use `concat=n=2:v=0:a=1`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]atrim=duration=30[a];[0]atrim=start=45[b];[a][b]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```